# Wheezy: How do I create a .zip on the Pi?

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, pi-store

I have created a basic encrytion program for the Raspberry Pi in Python. I have decided to upload it to the Pi Store. According to the site, I need to create a `.zip`. I have already tried [using this example,](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=31163&p=297113) but I receive an error message.

```
An error occurred while accessing the archive:
```

How would I create a `.zip` archive file on the Raspberry Pi, preferably using the GUI interface?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Zip files are quite easy to create on the Pi.

It is as simple as running one command:

```
zip -r zip-name directory-to-be-zipped
```

This will zip `directory-to-be-zipped` into a zipfile named `zip-name`. The `-r` bit is necessary, otherwise the program that makes zip files won't go into directories recursively.

Comment: Zip: command not found

Comment: @Matthew `sudo apt-get install zip unzip`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it specifically have to be .zip or can it be any compression? If it has to be .zip, first make sure the "zip" package is installed and do this in a terminal:

```
zip zipfile_name file1 file2 file3
```

I know you said preferably through a GUI, but that's the fastest way that I know. I'm not sure how well-versed you are with globbing, but you can speed it up a lot if you have a lot of files to include. The simplest way, though, would probably be to move all the files you want into a directory, then do:

```
zip zipfile_name /path/to/directory/
```

On the other hand, if you just want really good encryption, you can use the 'tar' utility to encrypt with bzip2. It's command-line too, but just as easy to use.

```
tar cvjf filename.tar.bz2 /path/to/directory/
```

While daunting at first, the options break down easily: 
c: create 
v: verbose(to tell you what's going on)
j: bzip2
f: filename

BONUS: If you ever come across any .tar file, the easiest way to extract it is with the following command:

```
tar xvf filename.tar.xxx
```

x: extract
v: verbose
f: filename

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: For extraction you also need the j or z flag for bz2 and gz compressed archives.

Comment: xvf flags work just fine with bzip and gzip. You don't need to explicitly set them(unless you're creating an archive, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the info. When I started with Linux (19 years ago!), this was not the case. Good to know that this has changed.

Comment: Anytime, I figured that was the case. Old habbits die hard. :)